# convert to md5 is wrong in php

Tags: php, md5, urlencode

I have a form in which I am taking username and password from user,
and I am converting the password to md5. Then I insert it into database. In user login form, I take the password and convert it to md5. Then I compare both passwords. It matches in some condition but fails if password = `p@$$w0rd`.
What is the issue ? And what is the solution for this issue?

From my form to database password of `p@$$w0rd` to md5 is `b7463760284fd06773ac2a48e29b0acf` and from login form it is `e22bb24ca616331cb92a48b712034bc3`

Code from registration form

```
$password = trim($_POST['password']);   
$dpassword = md5($password);
```

And from login form
`$passwd = md5($password);`

```
$sql = mysql_query("select * from create_dealer where (dealer_email='$user' && password='$passwd')");
```

Comment: Code examples how the passwords get processed for insertion and comparison would be nice

Comment: Then var_dump() the password received from the login form to see what it really is.... this is a technique known as "debugging"

Comment: Security advise: Don't use `mysql_`-functions. They are deprecated

Comment: or pure md5 for passwords :P

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is with  quotes.

```
echo md5('p@$$w0rd');// echoes b7463760284fd06773ac2a48e29b0acf
echo md5("p@$$w0rd");// echoes e22bb24ca616331cb92a48b712034bc3
```

When you use double quotes, `$w0rd` is considers as an undefined variable and replaced with an empty string.

```
echo md5("p@$");// echoes e22bb24ca616331cb92a48b712034bc3
```

Comment: Good catch, well spotted

Comment: But I am using from variable via post method

Comment: Its because, even i had did a same mistake for the first time when i used `md5()`

Comment: @LOKESH use single quotes. I think you r not using any quotes.

Comment: @LOKESH Please show more code then since what you have so far isn't enough to tell what's really going on.

Comment: what he is saying is that your password containing $ character and within no or double quotes will be considered partially a variable

Comment: When you're using $_POST['password'] it should not be parsed as being "P@$$W0RD" - it should be just plain 'P@$$W0RD' and PHP should not be parsing the variable in there. That only happens when you _declare_ a string with double quotes. EDIT: Otherwise it would be pretty easy to hack stuff, right? Fill in as username $_SESSION['blar'] and there's your code injection

Comment: @LOKESH Are you still facing the same issue??

Comment: No My problem is solved. Perfect & Instant Solution @NiranjanNRaju

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the same method to hash both inputs, then most likely you get some whitespaces or some characters escaped within one of them, make sure the inputs are EXACTLY same before hashing them.

You may also just remove the md5 call for test and see if plain text passwords match, I bet not. It might be just your SQL that returns the wrong row...