# sha1 is not working in password encryption

Tags: php, sha, password-hash

I am using sha1 encryption for encrypting my password, but I am facing problem with that. For some users, login is not working.

my code,(in sign up)

```
// all validation is done here
$password = sha1($_POST['password']);

// inserting data is here
```

in login my query is

```
$email     = $_POST['email'];
$password  = sha1($_POST['password']);

select * from users where email = $email and password = $password and status = 1 and deleted = 0;
```

one of the user facing problem with password,

> im$$man

Am I doing some thing wrong.

please help me.

Comment: I guess, you should have problem with all users instead of one for this code as this code do not sha1 hashing to `$_POST['password']` before select query. So ideally none of your users should satisfy by the query results.

Comment: i forgot to add there... but its not working for only few users...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the problem is here,

sha1 treats `$man` in `im$$man` as variable, so it will be evaluated as null since you dont have any value for that.

some thing like this,

```
sha1("im$$man");// will echo 17cf5ec2752a9a7f0077c904f60b64f23ba2534d
```

is also equal to

```
sha1("im$");// will echo 17cf5ec2752a9a7f0077c904f60b64f23ba2534d
$man is evaluated to null.
```

Output is same for both the input(input is different though)

To get expected result, avoid double quotes there,

```
sha1('im$$man');// this will give correct output
```

Output is

```
850caa44549443778fe005f466766d5d6d413692// correct output.
```

Similar problem with [md5() here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33253075/convert-to-md5-is-wrong-in-php/33253163#33253163)

Comment: actually im directly taking the value from $_POST.

Comment: thank you sir... problem was in generation of password with double $. Im generating password on forgot password. There if im getting 2 $, im getting this issue. Thanks a lot sir.i saw one more answer also. you are genius, thanks sir...

Comment: Yes... U need to take care about double $ symbol while generating password... And also use single quotes...

Comment: Glad I could help you:)

Answer (score 6):

> I am using sha1 encryption for encrypting my password,

Nope. SHA1 isn't encryption, it's a hash function. [Understanding the difference between encrypting and hashing](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/08/you-wouldnt-base64-a-password-cryptography-decoded) is crucial to implementing this safely:

- Doing it right: [use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php)
- Doing it wrong: [Encrypting with TripleDES-ECB](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2013/11/04/anatomy-of-a-password-disaster-adobes-giant-sized-cryptographic-blunder/)

Also, the way you wrote your query leads me to believe it is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/preventing-sql-injection-in-php-applications-easy-and-definitive-guide).

Comment: That article on Adobe was a good read, even if it's a couple of years old. Good thing I've never been an Adobe customer!